Difficulty parsing XML
This c# code:
HttpClient apiP21 = new();
apiP21.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("client_secret", "thesecret");
apiP21.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
apiP21.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("username", "theuser");
var tokenRequestDataContent = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
var tokenResponse = apiP21.PostAsync("theendpoint", tokenRequestDataContent).Result;
if (!tokenResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    return BadRequest("Could not get Security Token");
}
string tokenResponseRaw = tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

XmlDocument tokenResponseXML = new();
tokenResponseXML.LoadXml(tokenResponseRaw);
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new(tokenResponseXML.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("act", "http://distributionsuite.activant.com");
XmlNode accessTokenNode = tokenResponseXML.SelectSingleNode("//act:AccessToken", nsmgr)!;
string accessToken = accessTokenNode?.InnerText!;

For some reason, I am getting null in accessTokenNode.  I don't understand why.
Here is the XML visualizer output from tokenResponseRaw (I've omitted the actual token).  I just need to get at the security token.  What am I doing wrong?
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<act:Token xmlns:act="http://distributionsuite.activant.com"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <AccessToken>thetoken</AccessToken>
    <TokenType>Bearer</TokenType>
    <UserName>theuser</UserName>
    <ExpiresIn>86400</ExpiresIn>
    <RefreshToken/>
    <Scope>/api;/data;/odata:inv_mast,inv_loc,users,roles,pricing_library,inv_sub,serial_number</Scope>
    <SessionId>d0232f06-69fb-499d-bf41-4d8e6ae9b6c2</SessionId>
    <ConsumerUid>7</ConsumerUid>
</act:Token>

I was expecting to get the AccessToken node, but get null...

Do you have to use XmlDocument? If you can use XDocument (LINQ to XML) instead, it makes working with namespaces much simpler.

As already suggested by @JonSkeet, here is LINQ to XML based solution. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007 onwards.
c#
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<act:Token xmlns:act='http://distributionsuite.activant.com'
           xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
           xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
        <AccessToken>thetoken</AccessToken>
        <TokenType>Bearer</TokenType>
        <UserName>theuser</UserName>
        <ExpiresIn>86400</ExpiresIn>
        <RefreshToken/>
        <Scope>/api;/data;/odata:inv_mast,inv_loc,users,roles,pricing_library,inv_sub,serial_number</Scope>
        <SessionId>d0232f06-69fb-499d-bf41-4d8e6ae9b6c2</SessionId>
        <ConsumerUid>7</ConsumerUid>
    </act:Token>");
    
    string AccessToken = xdoc.Descendants("AccessToken").SingleOrDefault()?.Value;
    Console.WriteLine($"AccessToken: {AccessToken}");
}

Output
AccessToken: thetoken


That worked, thank you for the help!
